# Binary search tree -- ordering

Tags: sorting, height, binary-search-tree

If we have V values for a search tree where the values are V= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} **inserted from right to left**

And we are to order it to get the largest and shortest height possible -- how would we do it? Would it require the best and worst (lg2 (n+1)) case??

And would the orderings be unique?

Thanks -- I kinda understand but am not sure on what steps i should take.

Answer (score 0):

The tallest such trees are created by inserting the values from a sorted sequence

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

or

```
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

The shortest tree is made by ordering the values via a recursive algorithm that finds the median then processes the left and right subtrees recursively:

```
4 2 1 3 6 5 7
```

This produces a tree of logarithmic height:

```
     4
   /   \
  2      6
 / \    / \
1   3  5   7
```

Here the median is 4, so that goes first.

```
4
```

Now you have a partition for the left (1, 2, 3) and right (5, 6, 7).  To order the left, start with its median, 2.  Now you have 1 and 3 for its subtrees.  These are 1 element sets so that's your base case.

```
4 2 1 3
```

Now process your right subtree (5, 6, 7), starting with 6.

```
4 2 1 3 6 5 7
```

Comment: What if the values are not in an order like {4,3,2,7,5,6} -- would we do it the same way.. or put it in order first?

Comment: You don't have to sort first, as long as you have a way of finding the median and then partitioning what is left into the ones that are smaller and the ones that are larger than the median.  In your example: start with the median, which is 4.  Then partition into the smaller values {3,2} and the larger values {7,5,6}.  The left tree can be either 2-3 or 3-2 (it doesn't matter).  The right tree will start with its median, 6, then 5-7.  So you will have the order 4-3-2-6-5-7.  That makes the tree    ((2)3)4((7)6(5))

Comment: I understand that we wont have to sort and simply just take the median but what if the values were to be inserted from right to left.. would we still be taking the median -- wouldn't that change the order?

Comment: If you need to go right to left, use the same algorithm but build your sequence from right to left and make the necessary adjustments.  Or use the algorithm described and reverse the sequence as the last step.

Comment: Oh sorry, the one in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The largest height is easy; put them in order:

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    ...
```

With the smallest height, sort them, take the middle as the root, and put the two sides one either branch. Rinse and repeat.

```
        3
       / \
      2   5
     /   / \
    1   4   6
             \
              7
```

So... n for the first one, and log_2(n) for the second (rounded up).

Comment: So, the orderings don't seem particularly unique, i roughly have this down but i am a little confused as to the log to the base 2 (n) part in the worst case -- If you could explain that a little.

Comment: Also, what if our values were V = {20, 11, 4, 15, 40, 30, 35}.. would it work in the same manner or would we put it in order first from 4-40?

Comment: You don't have to sort them first.  The important thing is that you take the median and then partition them.  So in your example the median is 20, so that goes first.  Then the next thee numbers will come from {11,4,15} and then the next three after than from {40,30,35}.

Comment: And would it make an changes if we were to insert it from right to left?

Comment: @RayToal, no you don't have to sort them. But for a beginning, that's the best way to find the median.